# TextBox errors in VS after updates

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I just got a security update for Windows 10 and I noticed it included a framework security update. I also very recently updated to Visual Studio a 16.4.3.

Code that has been quietly sitting in my interesting section suddenly produced errors.

```
    Dim ctrl = TextBox1
    If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then ctrl.Text = String.Empty
```

Red squiggle under `TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox` saying "Expression of type 'TextBox' can never be of type 'TextBox'".

Another example

```
Public Sub CLEAR_TEXT(ParamArray text As TextBox())
    text.ToList().ForEach(Sub(s) s.Clear)
End Sub
```

Red squiggle under `s.Clear` saying "Clear is not a member of TextBox"

I have cleaned the solution, closed Visual Studio and restarted the computer.

Any thoughts why these are producing errors.

Comment: That first code snippet seems kinda crazy to begin with. Did you write that just to test something? Regardless, the only legitimate reason I can see for that would be if you had a name clash on `TextBox`. If you right-click `TextBox` in that code and select *Go To Definition*, where does it take you? Is it somewhere that is NOT the WinForms `TextBox` control?

Comment: If it does appear to be a VS issue, I'd try a new project and see if the same thing happens. If a new project works, migrating everything to the new project using *Add Existing Item* may be best option.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, I just pulled that out of a more extensive snippet and added the `Dim` to show what it was doing. You were correct. I was testing some other code and added the web controls import. Conflict! Thank you! I thought I was loosing what is left of my mind.

Comment: Thank you. I'm in a relatively built-up area so fairly safe but things are pretty desperate in areas with more bush and the loss of animal life and habitat is painful to ponder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code was in a test program I use to play around with posters questions. I was looking at some web code and added `Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls` to my WinForms application. This addition has a definition of TextBox that conflicted with the WinForms definition. @jmcilhinney commented for me to

> right-click TextBox in that code and select Go To Definition

I did this and found the error. I removed the Imports and all was well. I also could have  fully qualified the TextBox as a WinForms TextBox.

Comment: Did you fix both errors after you removed the Imports?

Comment: @JulieXu-MSFT Yes. Thank you. I had added that imports just temporarily to check some code and forgot to remove it.